# CS50 x 2023 | Pset 4 Recover

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, cs50

I have been working on this problem from CS50's Week 4 Problem Set [Recover](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/recover/). Check50 says, and I qoute, ":( program is free of memory errors". I closed the files I work with, so I don't understand what's causing the memory errors.
I have tried changing `while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inputFile) != 0)` to `while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inputFile) == 512)`, but that didn't result in a significant change.
Can you help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE; // define BYTE as 8 bits

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Wrong usage\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Open file
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inputFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read 512 bytes into a buffer, the buffer is "bytes"
    BYTE buffer[512];
    int counter = 0; // to count the number of files created/read
    FILE *outputFile = NULL;
    char filename[8]; // xxx.jpg + '\0', it is 8 because we need the null character too since its a string

    // Check if this might be the beginning of a 512 byte JPEG file
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inputFile) != 0)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter); // for creating a new file
            outputFile = fopen(filename, "w");
            counter++;
        }
        if (outputFile != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outputFile);
        }

    }
    // Close files
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please open the files in binary mode: `fopen(argv[1], "rb");` and `fopen(filename, "wb");`

Comment: How many files do you open? And, how many files are closed in this code???

Comment: You didn't `fclose` the previous open file (if any), before you open the next one. Just before the `sprintf` it needs `if (outputFile != NULL) fclose(outputFile);`

Comment: I forgot that I needed the to close the outputFile in the loop, I have closed it before sprintf and it is free of memory errors now, thank you @WeatherVane

Comment: OT: `char filename[8];`... There's (likely) 8Mb of stack available, and this buffer size has been calculated to the exact byte count necessary... If `counter` reaches 1000+, this buffer will **not** be big enough to hold the string it's assigned. Please change this to something like 128, or a _larger and reasonable_ size! Don't be stingy with these things.

Comment: PS: the code verifies opening the source file, but doesn't check the desired output file(s) are successfully opened...

Comment: ... and then you'll try to `fclose` a NULL pointer after the loop. Better to change your `if (outputFile != NULL)` to `if (outputFile == NULL)`, abort, and make the `fwrite` unconditional. Also, in this case the files might be exact multiple of 512 size, but generally you should capture the number of bytes read by `fread` and `fwrite` that number of bytes.

Comment: That last comment has an error, because you do need to test `if (outputFile == NULL)` before writing. I understand from previous Qs on this task that the input file may not begin with a header block, but be the relic of a the broken file passed to this recovery system. So until a header block is recognised (and a file opened) the data should be discarded.